# When I raise event it is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

In my `MainViewModel` I suscribe on `Event`:

```
var uc = new MyUserControl();
uc.ViewModel.ValueTypeChangedEvent += OnValueTypeChanged;
Control05 = uc;

StartMeasuring2();
```

My `BackgroundWorker` is:

```
private myUserControl Control05 { get; set; }

private void StartMeasuring2()
{
    _backgroundWorkerP2.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorkerCompleted;
    _backgroundWorkerP2.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerDoWork;

    if (_backgroundWorkerP2.IsBusy)
        _backgroundWorkerP2.CancelAsync();
     else
     {    
         _backgroundWorkerP2.RunWorkerAsync();
     }
}

private void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    while (!StopMeasuringP2)
    {
        const int measurementStatus = 0;
        var random = new Random();
        double measurementValue = random.Next(1, 9);
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Control05.ViewModel.UserControl1.ViewModel.LastDayMesswerte(dateTime,measurementValue, measurementStatus);
        Thread.Sleep(7000);
     }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is my LastDayMesswerte method in user control `ViewModel`:

```
public virtual void LastDayMesswerte(DateTime time, double measurementValue, int measurementStatus)
{
     if(measurementValue>=0 && measurementValue<3) 
          ValueType = "Alarm";

     if(measurementValue>=3 && measurementValue<6)
          ValueType = "Warning";

     else
     {
         ValueType = "Normal";
     }
}
```

My `ValueType` is property:

```
public virtual string ValueType
{
    get { return _valueType; }

    set
    {
        if (_valueType == value) return;
        _valueType = value;
        OnValueTypeChangedEvent(ControlId, MasterId);
    }
}
```

`OnValueTypeChangedEvent`:

```
protected virtual void OnValueTypeChangedEvent(int controlId, int masterId)
{
    ValueTypeChangedEventHandler handler;

    lock (_valueTypeChangedEventLock)
    {
        handler = _valueTypeChangedEvent;
    }

    if (handler != null) handler(controlId, masterId);
 }
```

So before I call `LastDayMesswerte` in my `BackgroundWorker`,  `_valueTypeChangedEvent` is not NULL. I set a breakpoint on first if-statement in method `LastDayMesswerte` and `_valueTypeChangedEvent` is already NULL. Why it is happening?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the remove method to see if that is called?

Comment: yes, it does not go to remove method

Comment: when you call OnValueTypeChangedEvent _valueTypeChangedEvent is null? And are you sure you call OnValueTypeChangedEvent on <b>uc</b>?

Comment: Did you try using 'volatile' so that data would be shared between threads?

Comment: @Siva Gopal: not yet, I'll try now

Comment: volatile doesn't share data between threads. But are the this objects of the add method and the OnValueTypeChangedEvent identical? Or do you access _valueTypeChangedEvent anywhere else?

Comment: @Dirk: I don't access _valueTypeChangedEvent from another places.

Comment: Have you checked if you work on the same objects and don't create a new ViewModel somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have one viewModel for mainWindow and one for userControl

Comment: I'd say you're working with different instances of MyUserControl. BTW, are you really creating uc in MainViewModel?

Comment: @SivaGopal `volatile` shouldn't be needed here, the `lock` blocks will create memory barriers, and all access to the field in question is inside of such blocks.

Comment: @Sasha: how do you pass `uc` to background worker thread?

Comment: @JeffRSon: I create uc in my mainViewModel and only one instance of my userControl is created, so I don't think that I am working with different instance

Comment: Show the code of `LastDayMesswerte` where an event is null.

Comment: @JeffRSon: Before executing first line it is already null

Comment: *What* is null? Explain with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken (your code is rather unusual - I wouldn't create a UserControl from a ViewModel which contains another UserControl in its ViewModel which itself also has a ViewModel), the problem is that in

```
Control05.ViewModel.UserControl1.ViewModel.LastDayMesswerte(...)
```

you call `LastDayMesswerte` in `Control05.ViewModel.UserControl1.ViewModel` but you've never set `ValueTypeChangedEvent` there. Instead you set it in `Control05.ViewModel`.

Comment: Yes, you are not mistaken. Thank you and everybody else for patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the background worker after execute:

```
var uc = new MyUserControl();
uc.ViewModel.ValueTypeChangedEvent += OnValueTypeChanged;
```

And also be sure that the instace of view model you are raising the event is your user control view model. Hope this tips helps...

**EDIT**

Had you tried to execute the action that raise the event in the other thread using a `SynchronizationContext`? Like this:

```
        //Register the events
        var currentSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += (_,__) =>
                                       {
                                           //some action in background
                                           currentSyncContext.Send((t) =>
                                                                       {
                                                                           //Action that raise the event
                                                                       }, null);
                                       };
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Maybe this works, try it...

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I'm starting background right after defining all events. In debug mode I found out that on my main threat I have right value for event, and on my background threat, which raises event is null. Do you know how to deal with this?